Network tab is not showing any data in Firefox, how to fix?
I am trying to see the Query String Parameters under the Network tab of Firefox's developer tools, but all the tabs under Network (Headers, Cookies, etc) show "No response data available for this request". Everything is working fine in Chrome.
I have tried the following, but I am unable to get developer tools working:

Firefox is up-to [Version 124.0.2 (64-bit)]
Turned off all extensions
In settings "devtools.netmonitor.filters" is set to ["all"]
In dev tools settings "Network" is checked under Default dev tools

Everything is working fine in Chrome, but I need it to work for Firefox as well (for an assignment).
HTML code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Inschrijfformulier</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Sign Up</h1>
  <form action="sign_up.html" method="GET">
    <label for="naam">Wat is jouw naam?</label>
    <input type="text" name="naam" id="naam">
    <input type="submit" name ="submit" id="submit" value="Versturen">
  </form>
</body>

Screenshots of dev tools:
network tab
settings

Same bug here on some POST requests (Firefox 115). Workaround : right-click on any query and "Save all as HAR". The data is there.


Clear cache and cookies.
Try in Safe Mode.
Create a new profile.


Thanks, tried all of that just now but still get the same message: "No headers for this request"
